# sh - Split File to Multiple Files

Tags: unix, sh, aix

I need a unix (aix) script to split a file to multiple files, basically one file per line, where the content of the file like:

> COL_1 ROW 1 1 1
>
> COL_2 ROW 2 2 2
>
> COL_3 ROW 3 3 3

... and the name of each file is the 1st column, and the content of the file the rest of the line, something like:

Name: COL_1.log

content:

> ROW 1 1 1

Thanks in advance,
Tiago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a while loop and read each line:

```
cat file | while read COL REST; do
  echo $REST > $COL.log
done
```

COL will contain the first word of each line 
REST will contain the rest of the line